# Best way to develop Thread safe Pool Object provider in Java, with ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: java, pool

On a networking app, which is handling hundreds of packets per second, in order to minimize GC and allocations, I've wrote a simple "PoolManager".
This PoolManager can be called from different threads, on a lock-free approach.

Here is the class:

```
public class ByteBufferPoolManager {

    private final static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuffer> byteBufferQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ByteBuffer> byteBufferNativeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public static ByteBuffer getByteBuffer(){
        var bb = byteBufferQueue.poll();
        if(bb == null){
            return ByteBuffer.allocate(1000000);
        }
        return bb;
    }

    public static ByteBuffer getDirectByteBuffer(){
        var bb = byteBufferNativeQueue.poll();
        if(bb == null){
            return ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1000000).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        }
        return bb;
    }

    public static void releaseByteBuffer(ByteBuffer bb){

        bb.clear();

        if(bb.isDirect())
        {
            byteBufferNativeQueue.add(bb);
        }
        else
        {
            byteBufferQueue.add(bb);
        }
    }
}
```

My 2 questions are:

1. Is there a thread safe way to remove the need to have the temporary variable `bb`, which can be null if the Queue doesn't have any objects?
2. On a situation where the queue does have objects to return, will the temporary `bb` cause a lot of GC, considering that technically just holds the reference for the object temporarily? Is there a way for me to check this?

Thank you.

Comment: I have used threadlocal for similar stuff.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the local variable `bb` is or might be a problem. Can you explain further?

Comment: @tgdavies trying to reduce GC to a minimum due to the high frequency the getByteBuffer() is called. On my app, it can happily occur over 1000 times a second.

Comment: I don't understand how/why you think the local variable `bb` could affect gc. Its lifetime is well defined.

Comment: @tgdavies hence my second question, trying to understand more and learn about gc. In my head I'm creating an object by creating the temporary variable `bb`, however, I'm not sure if GC doesn't happen since the reference that `bb` is never lost. Could you elaborate or provide some material for me to read on this? Thanks

Comment: You create an object when you use `new`, or some function which calls `new` like `ByteBuffer.allocate(1000000)` (which calls `return new HeapByteBuffer(capacity, capacity, null);`). Assigning a reference to another reference doesn't create an object.